# Programmatically open a UserForm from an external script / program / host application

Tags: activex, userform

Given that I have a UserForm embedded in one of the following:

- an Excel workbook named `c:\myBook.xslm`
- a Word document `c:\myDocument.docm`, or
- a PowerPoint presentation named `c:\myPresentation.ppm`

What Automation properties / methods do I need to use in order to open and display the UserForm from an external script / host application / program?

For example, let's say I have the following JScript running under WSH:

```
var app = new ActiveXObject('Excel.Application');
app.Visible = true;
var book = app.Workbooks.Open('c:\myBook.xlsm');

// open UserForm here
```

**How would I proceed to open the UserForm?**

Note: I am looking for a solution that would work with an arbitrary document. This precludes manually (but not programmatically as part of the script) adding a `Sub` to show the `UserForm`, which can be called from the external script.

Comment: Can you add the target Office Version you try to automate?

Comment: @BrunoBieri 2010+; does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to override the document open mehtods. At least for Microsoft Word and Excel:

```
' Word
Private Sub Document_Open()
  UserForm1.Show
End Sub

' Excel
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

At word and excel document open, the dialog will be shown.

For Powerpoint its a bit more complicated:

[How to auto execute a macro when opening a Powerpoint presentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306007/how-to-auto-execute-a-macro-when-opening-a-powerpoint-presentation)

---

**Update**

After additional information in the question this is not a solution anymore. A starting point how to create code an add it to a VBA project can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34838194/1306012

Also this website provides additional information: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: In the `c:\myBook.xlsm` add a method `Workbook_Open()`. This method will be executed at opening the Workbook. Once your code executes the line `var book = app.Workbooks.Open('c:\myBook.xlsm');` the mothod should be called and therefore your userform being showed.

Comment: Ah, I understand. After your question update my proposal is not applicable anymore.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use the `Run` method but also for that you need a macro in the document to call which would show the UserForm. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-run-method-excel To me there is no way to directly call a UserForm from "outside" a VBA macro itself.

Comment: Unless it's possible to create such a macro from the external program, and then call the created macro.

Comment: I would like to proof me wrong but to my knowledge the macros are saved in a binary format within the document. In case you know how to create this binary format yourself, modify the document, save it temporarly and then open it... Then I could work. By the way, how do you know how the name of the `UserForm` within a document if you don't know the document itself?

Comment: I think it is possible to use the VBA Addin API to [add code modules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/add-method-vba-add-in-object-model), and view the existing UserForms in a document, based on the [**VBComponent**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/vbcomponent-object-vba-add-in-object-model)'s [**Type**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/type-property-vba-add-in-object-model) property.

Comment: I found a starting point here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34838194/1306012 In the comments of this answer there is also a reference to this page: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx