# PowerPoint - how to run a macro automatically?

Tags: powerpoint

I'd like to run a macro that sets the zoom to 100%, something like `Windows(1).View.Zoom = 100`, every time ANY file is opened in PowerPoint. The files are already created, so using a template to set the zoom is not possible. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a way (that I am aware of) to do this through a macro or powerpoint add-in. You might be able to do it using a custom web add-in but I don't have enough experience with that to provide an example.

After looking around there have been a few success stories. One of which is creating a custom UI element and then adding an onLoad hook to that.
Here is [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38295674/7442012).
Here is a link to the [Custom UI Editor Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn/screencasts/) However I had no luck in getting it to work. I *believe* (This is only my theory) that it is not compatible with the latest .NET framework.

If you do end up trying to do this, here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/31f152d6-2a5d-4b50-a867-9dbc6d01aa43) to the xml formatting documentation for UI elements. And a link to a little [tutorial](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01216-Create-an-ADD-IN-with-Ribbon-buttons-that-run-macros-when-clicked.htm) related to this.

Sorry I couldn't be of more help. This should at least get you started. If anyone else has a simpler way I would love to know as well.

Comment: I'll give +1 for the effort, I appreciate the information