# VBA Powerpoint how to Macro_BeforeRun?

Tags: vba, event-handling, copy, powerpoint, savechanges

is it possible to trigger event s.t. that a document is saved before Macro ∀ VBA Module run ?

Comment: Why not call the save-command directly from the macro?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "how to trigger an event before a presentation is saved" then the answer is as follows. This is a multi-step process.

1. Add a Class module (not a Standard module) called CEvents and add the following code to it:

```
Dim WithEvents ppApp As PowerPoint.Application

Sub Initialise()
    Set ppApp = PowerPoint.Application
End Sub

Private Sub ppApp_PresentationBeforeSave(ByVal Pres As Presentation, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Before save for " & Pres.Name
End Sub
```

2. Follow the process as described in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38295674/11318818
3. In the same Standard module that you put the `MyOnloadProcedure()` procedure, add a module-level declaration: `Dim mEvents As CEvents`
4. In the `MyOnloadProcedure()` procedure, replace `MsgBox "Hello"` with:

```
Set mEvents = New CEvents
mEvents.Initialise
```

5. Save your presentation (it must be macro-enabled eg .pptm). Close and re-open your presentation. Click save to test and you will see the message box.

Note that as soon as you make any module-level edits to your VBA code, the `PresentationBeforeSave` event will stop triggering until you close and re-open the Presentation ... this is because the module-level variables loose state when you make such edits, state is then re-set when the presentation is re-opened.